# Loop in table row & display data which is available in array using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop in a table row 16 times with 2 elements of array. I know I can't loop 16 times with 2 elements of data but I want to display a table which has 16 row and only first 2 row will have data and others will leave blank. 
Same as the image below

[image: img here]

I have tried this code but its not what I want

```php
<th>No</th>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th> 
for($i=1; $i<=16; $i++)
{
<tr>
<td> echo $i </td>
foreach($array as $a){
<td> $a->id </td>
<td> $a->name </td>
}
</tr>
}
```

Comment: So, output array data and then iterate 14 times.

Comment: no, not like that. :(

Comment: _"I have tried this code but its not what I want"_ - I can see why. That would just output the PHP-code as text since you're not having them in any PHP-blocks.

Comment: And like what then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through your entire array, 16 times.  I assume that your array only has 2 elements in it.  I'm going to assume it may not *always* have 2 elements in it, and if it has, say, 8 elements in it, you want the first 8 rows populated with data, but you always want 16 rows to display?

Additionally, I'm assuming that your `$array` variable is numerically indexed.

If all of that is true, then what you want is to eliminate your `foreach`, and just access the array element by index:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php for ($i=0; $i<=15; $i++) {
    if (!empty($array[$i])) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $i+1; ?></td>
        <td><?= $array[$i]->id; ?></td>
        <td><?= $array[$i]->name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    else { ?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Note that PHP arrays are zero-based, hence why I did 0-15 instead of 1-16.

Comment: Great!  If your problem is solved, consider accepting this as correct, so that future visitors will know you're not still looking for answer.

Comment: Yes i did brother

Comment: The solution is solid but as a note, you should make an effort to use the alternative control structure for readability: https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php - Slightly off topic, but worth knowing :)

Comment: Decisions like that will likely be driven by the style conventions adhered to by the company or group you're working with.  For one, I don't find the alternative syntax more readable and I've never seen it recommended.